# efrench vs frenchb

Tags: packages, babel, french

What are the differences between `efrench` and `frenchb`? Are they compatible with one another (for example the use of `\og` and `fg` in `frenchb`)?

Why is `efrench` not in TeXLive even though its documentation claims that it is prioritary over `frenchb` when calling `\usepackage[french]{babel}`?

Comment: In the (rather difficult to find) documentation, one sees that B. Gaulle rants about ostracism by the TeX community. I'd say that "efrench" is a substitute for Babel `frenchb`, but I don't know to what extent; the doc claims it has `\og` and `\fg`.

Comment: It's not in TeX Live because it hasn't a free license.

Comment: Ah! That doesn't help for sure (and might very well weight in the balance as far as choosing which one to use...)!

Comment: efrench _does_ have a free licence -- lppl (what's more, it says so in the index.html); this ought to be good enough for it to be in tl, so i'll have a word with karl

Comment: karl berry (a) thinks the package too confused to go into tl, and (b) has noticed more than one licence statement in the bundle; i have mailed the maintainers of efrench, and they tell me they have a plan to sort it all out; this may take some time...

Comment: @Anon: Please convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`frenchb` was the original babel language package for French localization. As an alternative, Bernard Gaulle created the FrenchPro package (also known as `french`).

> Beginning 1999, the FrenchPro package was marketed as shareware, and Bernard
>   Gaulle alone owner of all rights. He died Aug. 2nd 2007. His wife Catherine
>   Gaulle, the heiress, gave authorization in that matter to the eFrench group in
>   order to maintain the whole work in the future.

The package is now (under the name [e-french](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/e-french)) [on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/language/french/e-french/) (from where the quote above comes), as [announced some days ago](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.ctan.announce/9086).

The package should find its way in TeX Live in a short time, as the new license is LPPL.